# How to write a conditional importxml formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking for help writing a working conditional importxml formula. The page (just an example) I'm referencing is: https://www.discogs.com/release/stats/6888950. In this page, I am searching for specific usernames. That I can do, but I want the formula to return results ONLY if the specific user has given a 5 star rating.

I haven't figured out an Xpath for the rating element, but I think it is in here:
class="star star5 icon icon-star-o" aria-hidden="true" data-value="5" role="none">

I'm sure this should be easy for someone knowledgable. Please reference my public, editable sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YTfYO_IeJR8p4GEH02YIDcOp9qJHT32x1hv13Grcyhw/edit#gid=0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the values for the attribute 'data-value', use an xpath_query of `"//*[@id='page_content']/div[1]/div/ul/li/span[@class='rating rating_read_only']/@data-value"`

Combine the output in a data range and use a query to filter.

```
=JOIN(",",
  QUERY({
    IMPORTXML($B$2,"//*[@id='page_content']/div[1]/div/ul/li/span[@class='user']"),
    IMPORTXML($B$2,"//*[@id='page_content']/div[1]/div/ul/li/span[@class='rating rating_read_only']/@data-value")
  }, "select Col1
      where (Col1 contains 'ben.edwin' or Col1 contains 'Grant1968' or Col1 contains 'jdk1974' or Col1 contains 'RecordChaser9' or Col1 contains 'Petur.Rouch')
      and Col2 = 5"
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It is working almost perfectly for me, but I'm also running into some consistent issues regarding: Error
Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1. Actual: xxx. I can't understand why this error appears in some cases and not others. Again, thanks again for your help so far :)

Comment: @Gruso https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131436/186471

Comment: @player0 Thanks! But I don't understand how to solve this issue still, bc each EXPECTED: # is different, varying from 2-25+. Is it possible to fix this in one formula that works for any EXPECTED quantity? Thanks again..